# Check website compatibility programmatically

Tags: android

Is there any way to find entered URL is compatible with Android mobile or not?

Ex- In my app when user entered any URL(google.com) it will show its compatibility.

Comment: Do you want to check if there's a special mobile version of the URI requested?

Comment: I want to check android 2.1 version onwards

Comment: Please - could you redefine your problem? I (and I guess others too) don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to enter url in my application, when click on Go button it will show, entered url is compatible with a mobile or not.I want to check this from android 2.2 version onwards.

Comment: GeneSys can u give idea about- what are the parameter need to consider when checking website compatibility with android mobile

Comment: I'm afraid what you're trying to achieve is not (automatically) possible. You could however maintain a list of URLs that you know are compatible and return true or false for the given URL (wheter or not it is in your whitelist).

Comment: when we will get response for entered url, is it possible to check Html tags for mobile compatibility?

Comment: Check out my answer for a heuristic algorithm. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said already in the comments, there's not really a way to find out if a mobile version of a site exists. You could however try a heuristic algorithm that can "guess" if it's compatible or not. A few ideas that come into my mind:

**Domain**
*Domain*
Mobile sites are often provided on a domain that starts with `m` or `mobile` instead of `www` so check for something like `m.domain.com` or `mobile.domain.com`.

*Url Path*
I have also seen that mobile versions of websites are provided on a special path - keywords are the same as in the domain section - so check for `www.domain.com/m/...` or `www.domain.com/mobile/...` or `www.domain.com/android/...`.

**HTML Source**
*Doctype*
If the website uses HTML5 chances are given that the site has been optimized for  mobile viewing - so request the site and check if the doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

*Meta Tag(s)*
Check if the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" ...` is set. Chances are good if this tag is provided, the website was optimized for mobile view.

*CSS Queries*
Check if the site requested has special media queries on the CSS - for example: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="handheld...` this could also indicate that a website is optimized for mobile viewing.